# PHP exec in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, exec

I have problem when excecute the exec function in while loop
I want to transfer xml file to server the problem is the transfer to server is success 
but the data xml is same at all, the data is still the first xml data
are the exec action is cannot be run in while condition ? or i must clear something before run the next while ?

```
mysql_connect("someaddress","root","somepass");
mysql_select_db("somedatabase");

    $t_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inbox_hmis WHERE ordernumber = '01' AND status = 'false'");
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($t_data)){

    $un_id_sms = $data['id_sms'];
    echo "$un_id_sms";
        $xmlget = "/var/www/sms/basedata/$un_id_sms.xml";
                        exec("curl -d @$xmlget http://apps.dhis2.org/demo/api/dataValueSets -H Content-Type:application/xml -u admin:password", $output);
                        $outx = $output[0];

        $outx_r = str_replace("'", '"', $outx);

        echo "$outx_r | ";
    }
```

`$un_ind_sms` is unique id and the name of xml file 
`$outx_r` is the xml data

Comment: why use command line curl and not the php curl library?

Comment: that is standard from my client

Comment: @OkiPrasastio, Your client is insane.

Comment: Is there a reason for your client to ask you to write a program but tell you how to do it?

Comment: @brad i concur....this code is f'd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting the content of variable `$output` before calling exec. E.g.

```
unset($output); // as recomended in php docs
```

Before the exec call will fix your problem.

As stated in exec documentation if the array of lines already contains data, then the new result will be appended to it.

Comment: Yep. [PHP Document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php): "...Note that if the array already contains some elements, ***exec()*** will append to the end of the array...".

Comment: maybe because $output is array of lines, you only output the first one. $outx=join("\n",$output) will output everything and maybe print what is expected?